# Bootstrap featured wide card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Any idea how can I fix the card above using Bootstrap4?
I'm trying to make the picture perfectly scaled to a fixed height card.
Right now, it is obviously stretched and I'm figuring out if there's a way to make it look better.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Niciabob/pen/LYVGyGV

```
.img__featured {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 does not provide classes for this. For this, you can use `object-fit` and `object-position` properties, such as `object-fit: cover`.

See this article for more information about `object-fit` and `object-position`: https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the image as the background of `.image_featured` and set it to cover like this:

```
.img__featured {
  background-image: url("https://www.theproche.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/neuromarketing.jpg");
  background-size:contain;
  background-size:100%;
  height: 700px;
}
```

but this method isn't good for SEO and not advised.

Comment: two properties set, the last one will prevail, and making bg image is not ideal for SEO reasons